# How to set input type 'Select' in ui_component grid in magento 2.1.16

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, backend

I just Create **ui_component** `Vender/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component`
and in this I user

```
<column name="check_status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
           <settings>
               <options class="PME\MakeAnOffer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Status\ProductStatus"/>
               <filter>select</filter>
               <dataType>select</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Status</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
```

now its works perfectly for 2.2.7 and 2.3.0 but in case of 2.1.16 it give me the error

[image]

and when I remove these lines which I mention in my code then its works perfectly how can I set this??? or any alternative in place of `<setting>` or `component`

Comment: the above code is for heading. You should use field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<column name="check_status">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">PME\MakeAnOffer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Status\ProductStatus</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

try this code

Comment: Sir I need the code for the **Grid**

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Thank you it works for me.